# Liferay Uber Module: package does not exist

Tags: liferay, osgi, build.gradle, liferay-7, bnd

I wrote a Liferay 7 module that uses [org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html).
The needed OSGi components [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45185733/how-to-use-a-third-party-component-in-a-modular-way-in-liferay):

```
mvn:org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-osgi/4.5.3
mvn:org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore-osgi/4.4.6
```

## Uber Module

Now I am trying a build an Uber Module containing these JARs plus my code, per [Option 3 - Make An Uber Module](https://web.liferay.com/en/web/user.26526/blog/-/blogs/osgi-module-dependencies).

So, I manually downloaded the two JARs to my project, then added this to my `build.gradle`:

```
runtime group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.3'
runtime group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore', version: '4.4.6'
```

... and this to my `bnd.bnd`:

```
Include-Resource: @httpclient-osgi-4.5.3.jar
Include-Resource: @httpcore-osgi-4.4.6.jar
```

## Problem

When I try to compile, at the `compileJava` step I immediately get:

```
error: package org.apache.http does not exist
```

Adding `compileOnly` groups in addition to the `runtime` groups in `build.gradle` seems to solve the problem, but is it the right thing to do?

Answer (score 0):

you may wanna read this :
[Embed thirdparty JAR using BND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554314/embed-thirdparty-jar-using-bnd)
tim mentioned there, that you additionally need to add the embedded jar to the bundle class path